# How to get OnItemClickListener for SimpleAdapter

Tags: android

```
 final ListView lv= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
 String[] from = new String[] {"a", "b","c"};
 int[] to = new int[] { R.id.textbutton , R.id.buttonlist, R.id.imgart};
```

that's my variable

n my code

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> fillMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            String[]ArrayStr = Func.split(resultString, "|*|");
            for(int i = 0; i < ArrayStr.length; i++){
                String[]AStr = Func.split(ArrayStr[i], "|**|");
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("a", ArrayStr[i]);
                map.put("b", AStr[1]);
                fillMaps.add(map);
            }

            // fill in the grid_item layout
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, fillMaps, R.layout.list, from, to);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);


            lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
            });
```

why it's still can't click?
whats wrong with my code?

sorry i'm noob in android...

Comment: 1.Is your code missing ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list)  2. If your activity extends from ListActivity then try using getListView().

Comment: @Salil my activity still extend activity so i don't need gedlistview  i think and my variable don't miss. the list show perfectly, but cannot clicked... i have change the code to custom adapter, but in custom adapter i can't put a static header n footer.. that's make my layout become suck..

Comment: do you have ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list)  in the onCreate() of the activity ?

Comment: [code]public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.marketing);
         ListView lv= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);[/code]that's i have :)

Comment: On click do you get any exception / errors ?

Comment: no errors, just not respond the toast that i want to showb :(

Comment: The Toast is not displayed or onItemClick does not get called ?

Comment: i think onitemclick does not get called... i have check it with change the toast with finish(); and the result is same :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class must to extend ListActivity and override 

    `@Override

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

                //do something

    }`

*EDIT*

`  public class ListaFicheros extends ListActivity {

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lista_ficheros);

    //....



    initLista(auxFile.listFiles());

}

private void initLista(File[]archivos){
      //....  

    ArrayAdapter<String> listaArchivos= new mArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.fila_list_fich,R.id.lista_fich_texto_fila, elemSinExt);
    setListAdapter(listaArchivos);

}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    int IDFilaSeleccionada = position;
    Intent intent = new Intent(ListaFicheros.this,InterfazLector.class);
    intent.putExtra("PATH", paths.get(IDFilaSeleccionada));
    intent.putExtra("NOMBRE", elementos.get(IDFilaSeleccionada));
    DoVibration.OK((Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE));
    startActivityForResult(intent, ID);
}`
```

Comment: @aracem become error at your code... with strange error like <code>Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token ")", ; expected
 - Syntax error on token "(", ; expected
 - void is an invalid type for the variable 
  onListItemClick
 - Syntax error on token ",", ; expected
 - Syntax error on token ",", ; expected
 - Syntax error on token ",", ; expected</code>

Comment: Are you sure your class extend ListActivity? In that case, to ensure, rigth click -> source -> override/implements methods and selecto onListItemClick . Dont copy/paste. I leave you a code(Its in spanish,i hope isnt a problem for you).

Comment: yes i'm sure, the onListItemClick in sub menu ListActivity :) so what i must do now?

Comment: See the edit of my first post (up).ITs a sample of one of my programs. (ListView, at the begining, allways have problems :P )

Comment: OMG i become so confuse, i need time to change n try your code... btw tq 4 your help @aracem tomorrow i will tell u the result

Comment: This sure can help you [android dev](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html). Then override onListItemClink  and i hope all work

Comment: You wellcome. If you have more problem and i can help you dont wait for ask me ;)